# "tangent" (the trig ratio) vs "tangent" (the geometric concept)

Tags: calculus, geometry, trigonometry, terminology, analytic-geometry

Do the terms "tangent" (the trigonometric ratio), which is defined as "opposite-side / adjacent-side", and "tangent" (of the curve), which is a line that touches a curve at a point, have the SAME meaning? If yes, how? Also: Is this same for "secant" and "cosecant"?

Comment: I think so tangent of a curve is the ratio of change in y-axis(opposite side) to change in x-axis(adjacent side) when the change is very small.

Comment: You might find the following question on the English Language & Usage SE helpful:  [What reasoning is behind the names of the trigonometric functions “sine”, “secant” and “tangent”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/40364/what-reasoning-is-behind-the-names-of-the-trigonometric-functions-sine-secan)

Comment: Do You mean $\frac{dy}{dx}$?@H G Sur

Comment: @Michael Seifert the article that you linked is helpful.but is there any article to know it completely ?

Comment: *same* meaning?  No. One's a real function, the other is a geometric object.  But related with a very direct application from one to the other.  Yes.  Definitely.  If you take a unit circle and measure the distance from the point of intersection to the point where the tangent line intersects the x axis that value is $\tan$ of the angle of the x axis to center of circle to the point of tangent.  Similar for secant and cosecant.

Comment: The value of angle function found by way of drawing a tangent has been given the same appellation , the same word.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1246168/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, they are not the same.

The tangent function $\tan$ is a function defined on numbers: you put in one number (namely an angle) and obtain another number (namely the quotient between opposite and adjacent leg in a right triangle with the given angle). The property of a line to be tangent to a given curve is something different. As is the operation of finding the tangent to a curve at a given point on the curve. The input here is a curve and one point on it, the output is a line. Since a line is not a number (at least in general), the two things are different.

That doesn't mean the two are not related. The post [*What reasoning is behind the names of the trigonometric functions “sine”, “secant” and “tangent”?*](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/40364/24078) pointed out by Michael Seifert contains a picture which demonstrates how various trigonometric functions can be seen as lengths related to a right triangle of unit length hypothenuse. There the value of the trigonometric tangent function is indeed the length of a certain segment along the tangent of the unit circle around one corner. But being related is not being the same.